# Is there any analogue to UIScrollVIew in Android Xamarin?

Tags: android, image, xamarin

I'm trying to create horisontal scroll view with images in it (like photo viewer, but not full screen). In iOS you can just add subviews to UIScroll view, is there any way to do the same on android? I'm using Xamarin if it helps.
I was trying to use multiimageview component from Xamarin https://components.xamarin.com/view/MultiImageView/
But there is no current index to retrieve, and i need selected image number

Comment: In Android it is called just ScrollView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Besides the Android ScrollView which is only for vertical scrolling you have a `HorizontalScrollView`.

Be careful with your memory. In Android you need to make sure you free your memory for the images when they go out of screen. Libraries like UniversalImageLoader or Picasso are helpful for that but I do not know if you can include them in Xamarin.

Comment: When I tried to add multiple views to HorizontalScrollView it crashed, saying that it can host only one child

Comment: yes, in Android a ScrollView and a HorizontalScrollView always need another Layout below. For your purpose a LinearLayout with orientation=horizontal seems to fit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using xml layouts, you can use the below

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" >
```

You can also do exactly the same thing via code (see ref https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Widget.HorizontalScrollView/).

Finally, if you are using Xamarin.Forms, you can use the ScrollView which is implemented on all platforms for you already and you can set the "Orientation".  (see ref https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView/)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you create thumbnail versions of the images otherwise you'll start to run into memory and performance issues when you have more than a couple images.  Here is code from my own application which subclasses BaseAdapter<> and displays photos as well as other content in a list.  I am doing the resizing on the fly within the list adapter, but there is no reason it couldn't be done first or cached and then reused.

```
// get the a photo item based on list position
var item = items[position];

// just getting photo info from my list of photos
var info = item.Data.Photos[0];

var options = new BitmapFactory.Options() { InJustDecodeBounds = true };
BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(info.Filename, options);

// Raw height and width of image
var height = options.OutHeight;
var width = options.OutWidth;
int inSampleSize = 1;

var viewWidth = 100;
var viewHeight = 100;

if (height > viewHeight || width > viewWidth)
{

    // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
    var heightRatio = (int)Math.Round((float)height / (float)viewHeight);
    var widthRatio = (int)Math.Round((float)width / (float)viewWidth);

    // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will guarantee
    // a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
    // requested height and width.
    inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
}

options.InSampleSize = inSampleSize;
options.InJustDecodeBounds = false;

image.SetImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(info.Filename, options));
```